# Two value in two lists, simplify the code

Tags: python

I have two lists, and I want to compare the value in each list to see if the difference is in a certain range, and return the number of same value in each list. Here is my code 1st version:

```
m = [1,3,5,7]
n = [1,4,7,9,5,6,34,52]
k=0
for i in xrange(0, len(m)):
    for j in xrange(0, len(n)):
        if abs(m[i] - n[j]) <=0.5:
            k+=1
        else:
            continue
```

the output is 3. I also tried 2nd version:

```
for i, j in zip(m,n):
    if abs(i - j) <=0.5:
        t+=1
    else:
        continue
```

the output is 1, the answer is wrong. So I am wondering if there is simpler and more efficient code for the 1st version, I have a big mount of data to deal with. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking for simpler or more efficient code? The first version you posted seems pretty simple to me.

Comment: So the first code is OK? if so I would not change it. Its easy to understand and maintain. Why forcibly make it more difficult to read and maintain by introducing some complex list comprehensions, etc?

Comment: @Mike thank you. I mean simpler and more efficient, because I have a lot of data to deal with.

Comment: @Marcin yes, the first code is OK. I mean I need more efficient code to deal with a lot of data, thanks!

Comment: How well-ordered is the data? Assuming the lists are sorted, or nearly so, you could benefit by short-circuiting your for loops once the difference is too large, as you can safely assume any remaining elements will also be outside the range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you could do is remove the `else: continue`, since that doesn't add anything. Also, you can directly use `for a in m` to avoid iterating over a range and indexing.

---

If you wanted to write it more succiently, you could use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
import itertools

m = [1,3,5,7]
n = [1,4,7,9,5,6,34,52]
k = sum(abs(a - b) <= 0.5 for a, b in itertools.product(m, n))
```

The runtime of this (and your solution) is `O(m * n)`, where `m` and `n` are the lengths of the lists.

---

If you need a more efficient algorithm, you can use a sorted data structure like a binary tree or a sorted list to achieve better lookup.

```
import bisect

m = [1,3,5,7]
n = [1,4,7,9,5,6,34,52]
n.sort()
k = 0
for a in m:
   i = bisect.bisect_left(n, a - 0.5)
   j = bisect.bisect_right(n, a + 0.5)
   k += j - i
```

The runtime is `O((m + n) * log n)`. That's `n * log n` for sorting and `m * log n` for lookups. So you'd want to make `n` the shorter list.

Comment: Nice work, Paul. And it's good to see someone using the oft-neglected `bisect` module.

Comment: The binary search version won't handle duplicates in the same way as the original, nor floating point "near duplicates" where two different n entries are within 0.5 of a single m entry. FWIW.  (If the data is all integer, then a micro-optimization could be to remove the floating point comparison.)

Comment: PS: Thumbs up for the idea of sorting.  Even with sloppy data ,you could come up with a merge-count pass that's O(m+n) on sensible data, which is still O((m+n) log(m+n)) overall.

Comment: @MikeHousky, perhaps you saw an earlier version of my answer? And if the data is integer, use set intersection! (Well, if the range is 0.5...)

Comment: @PaulDraper, yes...either I saw an earlier version or missed the second bisect call entirely. I wrote the "merge" version, but didn't post it.  It won't be _that_ much faster, and your version will still win if len(m) is much greater than len(n) (if len(m) > 2*log2(len(m))).

Answer (score 3):

More pythonic version of your first version:

```
ms = [1, 3, 5, 7]
ns = [1, 4, 7, 9, 5, 6, 34, 52]
k = 0
for m in ms:
    for n in ns:
        if abs(m - n) <= 0.5:
            k += 1
```

I don't think it will run faster, but it's simpler (more readable).

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler, and probably slightly faster, to simply iterate over the lists directly rather than to iterate over range objects to get index values.  You already do this in your second version, but you're not constructing all possible pairs with that zip() call.  Here's a modification of your first version:

```
m = [1,3,5,7]
n = [1,4,7,9,5,6,34,52]
k=0
for x in m:
    for y in n:
        if abs(x - y) <=0.5:
            k+=1
```

You don't need the `else: continue` part, which does nothing at the end of a loop, so I left it out.

If you want to explore generator expressions to do this, you can use:

```
k = sum(sum( abs(x-y) <= 0.5 for y in n) for x in m)
```

That should run reasonably fast using just the core language and no imports.

Answer (score 1):

Your two code snippets are doing two different things. The first one is comparing each element of `n` with each element of `m`, but the second one is only doing a pairwise comparison of corresponding elements of `m` and `n`, stopping when the shorter list runs out of elements. We can see exactly which elements are being compared in the second case by printing the `zip`:

```
>>> m = [1,3,5,7]
>>> n = [1,4,7,9,5,6,34,52]
>>> zip(m,n)
[(1, 1), (3, 4), (5, 7), (7, 9)]
```

pawelswiecki has posted a more Pythonic version of your first snippet. Generally, it's better to directly iterate over containers rather than using an indexed loop unless you actually need the index. And even then, it's more Pythonic to use `enumerate()` to generate the index than to use `xrange(len(m))`. Eg

```
>>> for i, v in enumerate(m):
...     print i, v
... 
0 1
1 3
2 5
3 7
```

A rule of thumb is that if you find yourself writing `for i in xrange(len(m))`, there's probably a better way to do it. :)

William Gaul has made a good suggestion: if your lists are sorted you can `break` out of the inner loop once the absolute difference gets bigger than your threshold of 0.5. However, Paul Draper's answer using `bisect` is my favourite. :)